# Triggers on AWS Trusted Advisor checks and/or recommendations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers

*We can put triggers on AWS Trusted Advisor checks/recommendations. So that when something happens on those check(s) we have a trigger on, a lambda function that we configured along with that trigger gets invoked and does what we look for-- alert us in some way, invoke a process for us, .. .*

Is this all accurate?

Assuming it is --

*Can we do this with any of the checks/recommendations of AWS Trusted Advisor?*

I'm guessing "yes" to both above but looking for verification.

We're looking to form a high-level view on AWS Trusted Advisor with no access/yet to AWS things to look these up-- AWS is another team under our umbrella.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure AWS Trusted Advisor to [send events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/cloudwatch-events-ta.html) to Event Bridge. Event Bridge can then trigger a Lambda function (among other things) with that event data.

Comment: Event Bridge sound like the Stream of DynamoDB-- DynamoDB events are captured/logged into Streams. then triggers are set on the Stream of the table (not the table itself) to trigger the lambda it's linked to. similar logic?

Comment: Event Bridge is an event bus. Yes it would be a stream of events. It does not use DynamoDB, and I'm not entirely clear on your comparison to DynamoDB.

Comment: an analogy rather than a comparison-- how we get alerted on "what's going on on the table/check". all clear-- thx again.